# Is it appropriate to follow the comma of an 'if' conditional with 'this'?

Tags: conditionals

Looking for some guidance on the appropriate way to structure an 'if' conditional.

The three examples we have on how to write a conditional:

> If you were to leave your windows open, this could make it easier for someone to break in.

> If you were to leave your windows open, it would be easier for someone to break in.

> If you were to leave your windows open, someone would find it easier to break in.

We each have different arguments for why each are correct or acceptable but nothing that we have been able to convince each other with.

If all three of the above are wrong, happy to take on any guidance on what the correct way to structure this would be.

Comment: All three are correct. The rule, for what it's worth (not a lot), is that when the *if*-string comes before the main clause, it should be followed by a comma. When it comes afterwards, no comma is needed between the clauses. It makes no difference whatsoever what the first word in the 'main clause' is.

Comment: That's why I'm wondering whether _conditional_ should be a grammatical term at all; it seems like everything sets or limits conditions for interpretation.

Comment: @JohnLawler But few constructions are self-effacing /deliberately designed to do a Mission Impossible ("this message will self-destruct ...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of your sentences are correct. There's nothing wrong with any of them.

Comment: "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." Please explain how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, Araucaria - Not here any more.
explained:

All three are correct. The rule, for what it's worth (not a lot), is that when the if-string comes before the main clause, it should be followed by a comma. When it comes afterwards, no comma is needed between the clauses. It makes no difference whatsoever what the first word in the 'main clause' is.